# Issue with Video component in qt qml for android build

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am developing a videoplayer application using video component in qt qml for android target. I have multiple screen in my overall application. The issue is when I navigate to home screen from the video screen, all the components in home screen is becoming irresponsive to click event.

I tried using other components which facilitates video playback (Mediaplayer along with VideoOutput), but the issue remains the same. Is there anything I need to handle when exiting from the video screen?

Comment: StackLayout? MediaPlayer? Can you show some code please?

Comment: Yes sure. I am using stackview for unloading the video screen and navigating back to the home screen. Back button is added in the videoscreen with the following onclick logic, `onClicked:  { video.pause();video.stop(); stack.pop() } `                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Video player implementation is, `Video { id:video;  width : parent.width; height : parent.height;source: path;}`

Comment: Sometimes I've had success when I move the backend component (i.e. Video / Camera / etc) to the root level of my application (I.e. it doesn't get created/destroyed with stack pushes/pops). The VideoOutput can stay. We have no problem creating and tearing that down. Just the backend components may implement asynchronous stop/start, so. the may need more time before you can destroy them. Move such components to the root means they're effectively "singleton-like" and you no longer suffer frequent creation/destruction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @StephenQuan, when I placed video component in the root of my application, issue got resolved.